# Strange Mapping Behaviour Jackson JSON

Tags: json, jackson

I've got a strange mapping Issue with Jackson on Android.

I've got a "Content" Class which should be used by the Jackson Mapper.

It looks like this:

```
public class content {
    private String header;
    private String subheader;
    private String bodytext;
    @JsonProperty("singleimage")
    private String image;
    @JsonProperty("uid")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("link")
    private String article;
    @JsonProperty("CType")
    private String cType;

    // Eclipse auto generated getters & setters
    ...
}
```

The corresponding JSON Object looks like this:

```
{
    "header": "xyz",
    "subheader": "abc",
    "bodytext": "abc",
    "singleimage": "abc",
    "images": "abc.jpg",
    "teaser_elements": "",
    "uid": "13",
    "link": "xyz.htm",
    "CType": "row_header"
}
```

Now when I use the Jackson Maper to create instances of Content from a provided JSON all fields of the content class get populated correctly - all except "cType".

I already tried to move the @JsonProperty("CType") annotation to the setCType Method but still no effect.

I don't get any Exceptions while mapping the class or anything else and as it seems to me that all mappings pretty much do the same (mapping to String) im kinda buffled why it doesn't work wit the "CType".

Any suggestions what the problem might be are highly appreciated.

Comment: Which Jackson version?

Comment: The current version I'm using is 2.1.4

Comment: Okay I finallay found the solution to my problem - it had to do with the Naming Strategy introduced in a transformer class. It was set to `CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`
So I added `@JsonNaming(CustomNamingStrategy.class)`to my Content Class. The CustomNamingStrategy handles all unusual Naming Convetions returend in the response.